# second appending of numpy array to list change the first entry in the list as well

Tags: python, list, numpy

In the following code:

```
E=np.zeros((2,2))
H=np.zeros((2,2))+1
L=[]
L.append(E)
E=H
L.append(E)
print(L)
```

the output is what I expect to be:

```
[array([[0., 0.],
    [0., 0.]]), array([[1., 1.],
    [1., 1.]])]
```

that is L[0] remains the same after the second appending.
However, for the code:

```
E=np.zeros((2,2))
H=np.zeros((2,2))+1
L=[]
L.append(E)
E[0,0]=H[0,0]
L.append(E)
print(L)
```

the output is

```
[array([[1., 0.],
        [0., 0.]]), array([[1., 0.],
        [0., 0.]])]
```

that is L[0] was changed after the second appending. can someone explain why there is difference?
I know that appending E.copy() is more safe but I do not understand what is the source for the difference since E[0,0] is numpy and not list.

Comment: You are replacing the element at position (0,0) of array `E` with that of array `H` at (0,0)

Comment: All you did was change one value in `E` and then append `E`. Why would you expect anything different?

Comment: What are you even trying to do? Why not `H = np.ones((2, 2))`?

Comment: in the second code I would expect the the first entry will remain zero matrix, and that the modified E will appear only in the second entry of the list

Comment: @JeruLuke OP is asking about L in that in the first code, L contained an original version of E and then a modified version of E, while in the second code, L only contained a modified version of E. the original version is lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example the variable `E` gets assigned to the same array as `H` refers to (the second array). The original relation of `E` to the first array is simply overwritten. That's why the first list element is unaffected in the first example.
In your second example, you change the content of the array to which `E` refers to and to which the first entry of that list has also be assigned to. Therefore it changes.

The action of `=` in python is rather explicit. Just assign some reference to a variable. Whatever that variable referred to before, simply does not matter.

You already had the answer by suggesting to use `copy` for appending to the list. If you want to keep track of the used matrices, you have to store a copy of each anyway. Otherwise they would get lost. So:

```py
E = np.zeros((2,2))
L = [E.copy()]
E[0,0] = 1
L.append(E.copy())
```

will give you

```
[array([[0., 0.],
        [0., 0.]]),
 array([[1., 0.],
        [0., 0.]])]
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. The motivation was from numerical scheme which is updated each time step only in some of the entries and I want to append the solution in this step. How would you suggest to change the second code in a clever way  so the previous  elements in the lists will not be changed?